# Adding image in Carousel Slider

Tags: php, html

i have a problem to do with Carousel Slider. i am adding an image and when i was listing in index.php. When i was adding and listing second image, it is adding just below as in pictures.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f43ok.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jS8b.jpg)

---

Slider.php

```html
<?php
    $veriler = $db->query("SELECT * FROM haberlerekle ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10",PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)->fetchAll();
    ?>

<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <?php $count = count($veriler);?>
    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <?php
     $i=0;
    for ($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) { ?>
        <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i; ?>"></li>
    <?php }  ?>
    </ul>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    <?php
    $j=0;
    foreach ($veriler as $row) {  ?>
        <div class="item <?php if($j==0) { echo "active"; } ?>">
            <div style="max-width:1100px; max-height:500px;">
                <img src=" <?php echo $row["haberekle_konu"]; ?>" alt="Los Angeles">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3> <?php echo $row["haberekle_baslik"]; ?> </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php $j++; } ?>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Codes below.

### ```html
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <?php
    $veriler = $db->query("SELECT * FROM haberlerekle",PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)->fetchAll();
    
    foreach ($veriler as $row) {  ?>
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div style="max-width:1100px; max-height:500px;"> <?php echo $row['haberekle_konu']; ?> </div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3> <?php echo $row['haberekle_baslik']; ?> </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php  }  ?>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

admin.php  -- a part of admin.php -- i think, all of the admin.php unnecessary. if it is important, now i can share.

```html
 <form>
       <input name="haberekle_baslik" size="100"></input><br><br>
       Başlık <br>
       <textarea name="editor1" cols="150" rows="30"></textarea><br>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Yayınla" style="margin-top:5px;">
       <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-info" role="button" style="margin-top:5px;">Yeni Ekle</a>
       </form>

       <?php
    
        if (isset($_REQUEST['editor1']) && !empty($_REQUEST['editor1'])) {
        $baslik = $_REQUEST['haberekle_baslik'];
        $content = $_REQUEST['editor1'];
        
        
        } else {
        echo "Lütfen Metin Alanını Doldurunuz";
        }

            if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
     
    
                if (isset($content) && !empty($content)) {
        
                }
            } 
      
    $haberekle = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO haberlerekle (haberekle_baslik, haberekle_konu) VALUES (:baslik, :konu)");
    $haberekle->bindValue(':baslik', $baslik, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $haberekle->bindValue(':konu', $content, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $isle = $haberekle->execute();
    if($isle) echo 'ok';
    else echo 'no';

    ?>
```

See i added images
For image store i selected "BLOB" but it doesn't work again.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jrc4W.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqzjh.jpg)
Thanks in advance

Comment: You used `carousel-inner` in foreach so you don't see other images. Read bootstrap carousel for details : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#slides-only

Answer (score 0):

**Below code is working with logics. Note: I have changed classname *carousel-item* to *item*.I hope it will help.**

```
    <?php
    $veriler = $db->query("SELECT * FROM haberlerekle ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10",PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)->fetchAll();
    ?>

<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <?php $count = count($veriler);?>
    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <?PHP 
     $i=0;
    for ($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) { ?>
        <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i; ?>"></li>
    <?php }  ?>
    </ul>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    <?php
    $j=0;
    foreach ($veriler as $row) {  ?>
        <div class="item <?php if($j==0) { echo "active"; } ?>">
            <div style="max-width:1100px; max-height:500px;">
                <img src=" <?php echo $row["haberekle_konu"]; ?>" alt="Los Angeles">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3> <?php echo $row["haberekle_baslik"]; ?> </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php $j++; } ?>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```